# which hidden state decoder use during the training?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, nlp

I am creating the language translation model with TensorFlow functional API.

This is the Encoder-Decoder model I have used.

```
# encoder 
encoder = tf.keras.Input(shape=(None, ))
enc_embd = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_train, embedding_dim)(encoder)

encoder_gru = tf.keras.layers.GRU(units, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L2(0.001))
output_e, hidden_e = encoder_gru(enc_embd)

# decoder
decoder = tf.keras.Input(shape=(None, ))
dec_embd = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_label, embedding_dim)(decoder)

decoder_gru = tf.keras.layers.GRU(units, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L2(0.001))
output_d, hidden_d = decoder_gru(dec_embd, initial_state = hidden_e)

final_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_label, activation='softmax', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L2(0.001))
output_f = final_output(output_d)
```

In the decoder section, I have initially initialized the value of **initial_state = hidden_e** (final hidden state of the encoder)

My question is that, is the state of the decoder change during the training process?, means that like, decoder has initial state = final state of encoder, then after first prediction, the state = first hidden state of decoder,  after second, state = second state of decoder until the final output of the decoder.

The further process be like

```
model = tf.keras.Model([encoder, decoder], output_f)

model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False), optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit([encoder_input, decoder_input], decoder_output, epochs=1, verbose=1)
```

Comment: As the weights are updated at every step, the `hidden_state` of the encoder will also change.

Comment: Not the encoder hidden state, I was talking about the decoder hidden state. The initial state of decoder is  final hidden state of encoder, I am asking that, will the decoder hidden state change on training the model?